# Cannot connect to an open port ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I am trying to connect to a redis server hosted on AWS. I used my private key to ssh into the instance, install and run the server. Now I wanted to access the server using the public dns of the instance and the port 6379 (on which the server is running). I have added the port 6379 to security group with `0.0.0.0/0` and `::/0` but when I telnet on this port, I get:

```
Trying [PUBLIC-DNS]...
telnet: connect to address [PUBLIC-DNS]: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: If connection is outright refused, then either server is not listening to the port on that interface, or iptables or firewalld on the instance itself are blocking the traffic. I would recommend checking that

Comment: Where should I check those?

Comment: As I said, on the instance. SSH into it and check these settings

Comment: Does it take some time to fail (which suggests no network connection), or does it fail immediately (which suggests Access Denied)?

Comment: Fails immediately

Comment: `sudo iptables -L` shows empty `Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)`. I am not sure what is rejecting the port outright? This is happening to only the ports I am opening from security group, others are getting timed out.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-ssh-troubleshooting/) troubleshooting document from AWS.
Furthermore, If you have enabled VPC Flow Logs, then you can trace vpc flow logs to check, which aws resource is rejecting the network traffic. For VPC flow logs information please refer [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/vpc-flow-logs-log-and-view-network-traffic-flows/) document from AWS.