# 111: Connection refused error when trying to connect to Flask app on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, flask, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm struggling to figure out how to connect to my Flask app, hosted on an AWS EC2 instance. It's running and deployed, but I'm getting the below error.

```
connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 71.228.155.185, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/favicon.ico", host: "my-site***", referrer: "my-site***"
```

I've seen other answers to a similar problem about making sure my app is pointed at port 8000, so I have the below in my initialization.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8000)
```

I've also gone in to my VPC security group and made sure all HTTP connections were allowed on port 80, which I think should enable me to connect.

Anyone else find this issue and resolve?

Comment: This means nginx cannot connect to flask app server. Check app logs, maybe it cannot start due to some error

Comment: If you ssh to the instance, can you confirm that your flask runs at `http://127.0.0.1:8000` when you `curl` it?

Comment: I confirmed the app is running in the logs. I'll try curl and see if that works

Comment: Check AWS VPC flow logs. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65341085/14843902

Comment: Confirmed I can start and stop the app from within SSH, but can't get to it from outside. Tried using the reachability analyzer and it shows it as reachable, so not sure what to do next. Is there a nginx or wsgi config file I'm supposed to have to handle this? The amazon docs say nginx passes to port 5000 automatically so tried switching to that but still nothing

Answer (score 0):

You talk about port 80 and port 8000....which one is the app using?  If it's 8000, then you'll need to allow port 8000 in your security group.

Port 8000, Source 0.0.0.0/0

You may want to tighten up the Source, depending on your needs.  This is more important if your server has a public IP.